# border spacing property doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the following table:
[image: table]

I have an outer border and one border at the bottom.
I got it all right, my only problem is that I can't get the space between the outer border and table (space of 20 px)
when I use border-spacing it doesn't work.

I would appreciate your help.

here is a sample of the code:
http://jsbin.com/AcanusA/1/edit

css code:

```
.outlined
{
  font:13px Tahoma;
  width: 70%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 10px solid #d0d0ff;
  margin: 20px;
  border-spacing:20px;
}

.center{
  text-align: center;
}

.side{
  text-align: left;
}

.lastLine{
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>web programming project 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exe2CSS2.css">
  <body>

    <table class="outlined">
      <tr id="headline">
        <th class="side">Item</th>
        <th class="side">Manufacturer</th>
        <th class="side">Size</th>
        <th class="center">Unit Price</th>
        <th class="center">Quantity</th>
        <th class="center">Total Price</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="firstCol">
        <td class="side">Corn Flakes</td>
        <td class="side">Kellogg's</td>
        <td class="side">18 0z</td>
        <td class="center">2.5</td>
        <td class="center">1</td>
        <td class="center">2.5</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="secondCol">
        <td class="side">Solid White Tuna</td>
        <td class="side">Starkist</td>
        <td class="side">5 oz</td>
        <td class="center">2.79</td>
        <td class="center">2</td>
        <td class="center">5.58</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="firstCol">
        <td class="side">Cream of Mushroom Soup</td>
        <td class="side">Campbell's</td>
        <td class="side">10.75 oz</td>
        <td class="center">1.00</td>
        <td class="center">2</td>
        <td class="center">2.00</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="secondCol">
        <td class="side">2% Lowfat Milk</td>
        <td class="side">Safeway</td>
        <td class="side">0.5 gal</td>
        <td class="center">1.99</td>
        <td class="center">1</td>
        <td class="center">1.99</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="lastLine">
        <td class="side">Extra-Wide Egg Noodles</td>
        <td class="side">Golden Grain</td>
        <td class="side">12 oz</td>
        <td class="center">0.87</td>
        <td class="center">3</td>
        <td class="center">2.61</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="bottom">
        <td>Total</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="center">9</td>
        <td class="center">14.68</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Including a sample on something like jsbin.com will usually help you get a faster/better response.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/AcanusA/1/edit

Comment: no, because you when you use the cellpadding in table you get spaces between all the rows.. and I want space only between the outer border and the table.. not inside the rows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a container div and put the border on that with some padding:

http://jsbin.com/AcanusA/8/edit

Html becomes:

```
<div class="outlined-container-1">
<div class="outlined-container-2">
<table class="outlined">
<tr id="headline">
<th class="si .......
</div>
</div>
```

Additional CSS:

```
.outlined-container-1
{
width:70%;
}

.outlined-container-2
{
border: 10px solid #d0d0ff;
padding:20px;
}


.outlined
{
  width:100%;
  font:13px Tahoma;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Obviously change the outlined name to something more relevant.

Comment: Note: modifying the layout for styling purposes can be syntactically incorrect.

Comment: I actually tried that at the beginning.. but then I couldn't get the border fitted to the table.. the border was too long from the sides..

Comment: Until the tools allow perfect separation of style and content, we will need things like this.

Comment: Ok.. but how can you limit the border from the right side if you do it in that way? an outer border in a div..

Comment: yeah here is a better edit removing the margin from the table. http://jsbin.com/AcanusA/4/edit

Comment: I am afraid the border is still too long from the right side.. but thanks anyway. I think there is no way to limit it.

Comment: You mean like this http://jsbin.com/AcanusA/5/edit ? anyway sounds like you can't change the html so this won't do, the answer you selected doesn't work on chrome by the way, the most popular browser.

Comment: very nice.. so what did you change?how is it short now from the side?

Comment: It was set to 70% width, which I removed, a div with no width will just fill it's parent.

Comment: For me the black line touches the outer border on Google chrome, it shouldn't do that, according to the design. Not sure why it's working for you.

Comment: well actually your solution is not correct after all.. because you restrict me to use the all page (100%), and I wanted only 70%...

Comment: Put another div around it and make that 70%, will work, perfectly cross browser.

Comment: I've updated my answer with that for completeness, http://jsbin.com/AcanusA/8/edit

Answer (score 3):

## Why doesn't `border-spacing` work?

`border-spacing` doesn't work because, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing,

> The `border-spacing` CSS property specifies the distance between the
>   borders of adjacent cells (**only for the [separated borders
>   model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-collapse)**).

Moreover `border-spacing` is the space between all cells, not only between border cells and the table, so it isn't what you want.

## Solution 1: wrapper

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 10px solid #d0d0ff;
  width: 70%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.outlined {
  font: 13px Tahoma;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 20px;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.side {
  text-align: left;
}
.lastLine {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table class="outlined">
    <tr id="headline">
      <th class="side">Item</th>
      <th class="side">Manufacturer</th>
      <th class="side">Size</th>
      <th class="center">Unit Price</th>
      <th class="center">Quantity</th>
      <th class="center">Total Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstCol">
      <td class="side">Corn Flakes</td>
      <td class="side">Kellogg's</td>
      <td class="side">18 0z</td>
      <td class="center">2.5</td>
      <td class="center">1</td>
      <td class="center">2.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secondCol">
      <td class="side">Solid White Tuna</td>
      <td class="side">Starkist</td>
      <td class="side">5 oz</td>
      <td class="center">2.79</td>
      <td class="center">2</td>
      <td class="center">5.58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstCol">
      <td class="side">Cream of Mushroom Soup</td>
      <td class="side">Campbell's</td>
      <td class="side">10.75 oz</td>
      <td class="center">1.00</td>
      <td class="center">2</td>
      <td class="center">2.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secondCol">
      <td class="side">2% Lowfat Milk</td>
      <td class="side">Safeway</td>
      <td class="side">0.5 gal</td>
      <td class="center">1.99</td>
      <td class="center">1</td>
      <td class="center">1.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lastLine">
      <td class="side">Extra-Wide Egg Noodles</td>
      <td class="side">Golden Grain</td>
      <td class="side">12 oz</td>
      <td class="center">0.87</td>
      <td class="center">3</td>
      <td class="center">2.61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bottom">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="center">9</td>
      <td class="center">14.68</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

It's the old way of doing it: set a a margin to the table and place it inside a wrapper element with a border.

Modifying the layout for styling purposes can be syntactically incorrect, but works on old browsers.

## Solution 2: outline

```css
.outlined {
  font: 13px Tahoma;
  width: 70%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  margin: 20px;
  outline: 10px solid #d0d0ff;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.side {
  text-align: left;
}
.lastLine {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="outlined">
  <tr id="headline">
    <th class="side">Item</th>
    <th class="side">Manufacturer</th>
    <th class="side">Size</th>
    <th class="center">Unit Price</th>
    <th class="center">Quantity</th>
    <th class="center">Total Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="firstCol">
    <td class="side">Corn Flakes</td>
    <td class="side">Kellogg's</td>
    <td class="side">18 0z</td>
    <td class="center">2.5</td>
    <td class="center">1</td>
    <td class="center">2.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="secondCol">
    <td class="side">Solid White Tuna</td>
    <td class="side">Starkist</td>
    <td class="side">5 oz</td>
    <td class="center">2.79</td>
    <td class="center">2</td>
    <td class="center">5.58</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="firstCol">
    <td class="side">Cream of Mushroom Soup</td>
    <td class="side">Campbell's</td>
    <td class="side">10.75 oz</td>
    <td class="center">1.00</td>
    <td class="center">2</td>
    <td class="center">2.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="secondCol">
    <td class="side">2% Lowfat Milk</td>
    <td class="side">Safeway</td>
    <td class="side">0.5 gal</td>
    <td class="center">1.99</td>
    <td class="center">1</td>
    <td class="center">1.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lastLine">
    <td class="side">Extra-Wide Egg Noodles</td>
    <td class="side">Golden Grain</td>
    <td class="side">12 oz</td>
    <td class="center">0.87</td>
    <td class="center">3</td>
    <td class="center">2.61</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bottom">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="center">9</td>
    <td class="center">14.68</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Add a transparent border and an [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) to the table:

```css
border: 20px solid transparent;
outline: 10px solid #d0d0ff;
margin: /* >= 10px */;
```

Note the outline doesn't increase table's width, so it will overlap surrounding elements. Then, it can be a good idea to use, at least, a margin of 10px.

**Browser support**

```
Chrome | Firefox (Gecko) | Internet Explorer | Opera | Safari (WebKit)
1.0    | 1.5 (1.8)       | 8.0               | 7.0   | 1.2 (125)
```

**Note**: Outlines may be non-rectangular. They are rectangular in Gecko/Firefox. But e.g. Opera draws a non-rectangular shape

## Solution 3: box-shadow

```css
.outlined {
  font: 13px Tahoma;
  width: 70%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #d0d0ff;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.side {
  text-align: left;
}
.lastLine {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="outlined">
  <tr id="headline">
    <th class="side">Item</th>
    <th class="side">Manufacturer</th>
    <th class="side">Size</th>
    <th class="center">Unit Price</th>
    <th class="center">Quantity</th>
    <th class="center">Total Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="firstCol">
    <td class="side">Corn Flakes</td>
    <td class="side">Kellogg's</td>
    <td class="side">18 0z</td>
    <td class="center">2.5</td>
    <td class="center">1</td>
    <td class="center">2.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="secondCol">
    <td class="side">Solid White Tuna</td>
    <td class="side">Starkist</td>
    <td class="side">5 oz</td>
    <td class="center">2.79</td>
    <td class="center">2</td>
    <td class="center">5.58</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="firstCol">
    <td class="side">Cream of Mushroom Soup</td>
    <td class="side">Campbell's</td>
    <td class="side">10.75 oz</td>
    <td class="center">1.00</td>
    <td class="center">2</td>
    <td class="center">2.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="secondCol">
    <td class="side">2% Lowfat Milk</td>
    <td class="side">Safeway</td>
    <td class="side">0.5 gal</td>
    <td class="center">1.99</td>
    <td class="center">1</td>
    <td class="center">1.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="lastLine">
    <td class="side">Extra-Wide Egg Noodles</td>
    <td class="side">Golden Grain</td>
    <td class="side">12 oz</td>
    <td class="center">0.87</td>
    <td class="center">3</td>
    <td class="center">2.61</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bottom">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="center">9</td>
    <td class="center">14.68</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use a transparent border with a [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow):

```css
border: 20px solid transparent;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #d0d0ff;
margin: /* >= 10px */;
```

Note the shadow doesn't increase table's width, so it will overlap surrounding elements. Then, it can be a good idea to use, at least, a margin of 10px.

**Browser support**

Use vendor prefixes (`-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`) for more support:

```
Chrome     | Firefox (Gecko) | Internet Explorer | Opera | Safari (WebKit)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10.0       | 4.0 (2.0)       | 9.0               | 10.5  | 5.1 (Webkit 534)
4.0 -webkit| 3.5 (1.9.1) -moz|                   |       | 5.0 (Webkit 533) -webkit
```

**Notes** (thanks @davidbuttar):

- In order to get box-shadow in IE9 or later, you need to set `border-collapse` to `separate`. Then, you lose the bar in your table.
- On Chrome, transparent borders don't stop the the bar in your table, and it reaches the box-shadow. I think it's a bug, and can be fixed using a white borders instead of transparent.

---

## Appendix: How does box-shadow solution work?

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

> Formal syntax: none | [inset? && [ <offset-x> <offset-y>
>   <blur-radius>? <spread-radius>? <color>? ] ]#

- **inset**: omitted, don't want it.
- **<offset-x> <offset-y>**: `0 0`, because we don't want to move the shadow.
- **<blur-radius>**: `0`, because we don't want a blurred shadow.
- **<spread-radius>**: `10px`,  because we want the shadow to expand to be 10px wide.
- **<color>**: `#d0d0ff`

> How could it be that you made the border transparent and the shadow
>   colored, and you got the opposite result?

That's because `border-spacing` defines a shadow **outside** borders (unless you use `inset`)

From the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#box-shadow):

> An outer box-shadow casts a shadow as if the border-box of the element
>   were opaque. The shadow is drawn outside the border edge only.

Comment: it seems perfect.. my only problem is that I am not allowed to do any design in html only in css.. can I move the  border-spacing="1" somehow to the css ?

Comment: The border-spacing is not a table attribute, but rather it is a CSS property and could be included in the CSS style sheet.  See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-border-spacing

Comment: could you please elaborate about the box shadow property ? I couldn't get how it works.. and why did you give 0 value?

Comment: how could it be that you made the border transparent and the shadow colored, and you got the opposite result?!?! the border is colored and the background is transparent.. I can't understand..

Comment: @davidbuttar You must have a very old version, because it should work on Chrome 10.0 and later (and 4.0 if using `-webkit`)

Comment: So no one else is seeing the black bottom line touching the purple border on chrome? Maybe it's fixable but just what I'm seeing, IE 10 is not even drawing the purple border. (using chrome 31)

Comment: @davidbuttar The black border on Chrome I think it's a bug, and can be fixed using a white border instead of transparent. And it seems IE needs `border-collapse: separate`

Comment: Adding border-collapse: separate; loses the black line.

Comment: @Shiran: Try my new solution: `outline`

Comment: Ya I have also just realized it today that css has the property outline.. :-)